# PowerPivot workbook as PerformancePoint data connection

Tags: performancepoint, powerpivot

I have uploaded a PowerPivot workbook to the PowerPivot Gallery and I am now attempting to use it as a data source for PerformancePoint, but I keep receiving  the following error when making the connection in Dashboard Designer:

> An error occurred connecting to this data source.  Please check the
>   data source for any unsaved changes and click on Test Data Source
>   button to confirm connection to the data source.

The file is not open and the Test Data Source button is greyed out.  What is the proper URL syntax? I'm  not sure if the URL is the problem either.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add it as a trusted source?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue described here. Does anyone have the resolution? I'm hoping the install described at http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/using-performancepoint-services-pps-with-powerpivot-sql-server-2012-rc0/ will be useful. I'm not an admin so I cannot install it myself. Before I ask the admins to drop what they are doing and try something are there other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

too late a response but anyway

i resolved the issue by increasing the max limit for excel services to required level. By default its 10MB and the powerpivot files are much larger.

SharePoint Central Administration, and go to Application Management > Manage Service Applications > ExcelServiceApp > Trusted File Locations and click on the appropriate Address. Under the Workbook Properties section you will see a Maximum Workbook Size